# Cloud DLP inspection scan to look for multiple infoTypes in same row

Tags: google-cloud-dlp, pii, bq

I have to run an inspection scan on a Big Query Table. My goal is to highlight/find a row only if it contains say, first_name, last_name, Phone_number & age infoTypes (*all in same row).
I'm new to Cloud DLP and have created a Job trigger (with all `infoTypes` i'm interested in) to scan data from a BQ table. I'm not really sure if `Inspection Rulesets` can help here.
Just in case my point is not clear: https://help.symantec.com/cs/DLP15.0/DLP/v54111221_v120691346/Coincidencia-con-3-columnas-en-una-condici?locale=EN_US

Answer (score 0):

Cloud DLP provides a set of built-in infoType detectors which allows you to specify by name, each of which is listed in InfoType detector reference. These detectors use a variety of techniques to discover and classify each type. For example, some types will require a pattern match, some may have mathematical checksums, some have special digit restrictions, and others may have specific prefixes or context around the findings.

However, there are additional options as shown in [here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-custom-infotypes) which you can use to further explore your use case.

"[Important](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference): Built-in infoType detectors are not a 100% accurate detection method. For example, they can't guarantee compliance with regulatory requirements. You must decide what data is sensitive and how to best protect it. Google recommends that you test your settings to make sure your configuration meets your requirements."

You can find some additional information [here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/concepts-infotypes#certainty).

Comment: I'm aware of infoTypes @cam my question was more about dlp scan mechanism. Sorry for not been able to address that in the question.